# parse html from string in android json response

Tags: android, html-parsing

The below string is what I retrieve from one of the  fields of json response >How do I get the value of `src` in the string below .I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
Getting better doesn’t stop because it’s getting colder. The best athletes don’t just overcome the elements, they embrace them with Nike Hyperwarm. Gear up for winter: <a href="/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Fhyperwarm&amp;h=4AQEBIq17&amp;s=1" rel="nofollow nofollow" target="_blank" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/www.nike.com\/hyperwarm&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.nike.com\u00252Fhyperwarm&amp;h=4AQEBIq17&amp;s=1&quot;);">http://www.nike.com/hyperwarm</a><br/><br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151882076318445" id="" title="" target="" onclick="" style=""><img class="img" src="http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-ash3/t15/1095964_10151882078663445_10151882076318445_40450_2013_b.jpg" alt="" style="height:90px;" /></a><br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151882076318445" id="" style="">Winning in a Winter Wonderland</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/) html parsing api to with dedicated functionality for html parsing and would also provide for an extensible solution.

For your case (I escape quotes and additional `\` to make it a valid `Java` string):

```
String str = "Getting better doesn’t stop because it’s getting colder. The best athletes don’t just overcome the elements, they embrace them with Nike Hyperwarm. Gear up for winter: <a href=\"/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Fhyperwarm&amp;h=4AQEBIq17&amp;s=1\" rel=\"nofollow nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" onmouseover=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\\/\\/www.nike.com\\/hyperwarm&quot;);\" onclick=\"LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;\\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.nike.com\u00252Fhyperwarm&amp;h=4AQEBIq17&amp;s=1&quot;);\">http://www.nike.com/hyperwarm</a><br/><br/><a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151882076318445\" id=\"\" title=\"\" target=\"\" onclick=\"\" style=\"\"><img class=\"img\" src=\"http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-ash3/t15/1095964_10151882078663445_10151882076318445_40450_2013_b.jpg\" alt=\"\" style=\"height:90px;\" /></a><br/><a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151882076318445\" id=\"\" style=\"\">Winning in a Winter Wonderland</a>\"";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
Element element = doc.select("img").first();
System.out.println(element.attr("src"));
Element element2 = doc.select("a").first(); // Get the anchor tag element
System.out.println(element2.attr("onclick")); // onclick as attribute for anchor tag
```

Output;

```
http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-ash3/t15/1095964_10151882078663445_10151882076318445_40450_2013_b.jpg
```

Comment: How do `I escape quotes and additional \ ` .PLease let me know?Thanks

Comment: Also how do I get `onclick` value ?

Comment: @jason I did it for demo purpose itself, try feeding your json response string to Jsoup and it would take care of parsing. For onclick, see the edit

Comment: I actually want value within onclick with corrent link .I am getting `\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.nike.com\u00252Fhyperwarm&amp;h=4AQEBIq17&amp;s=1&quot;)`  This is the link to redirect it to original link.I want that link .How do I get it ? CLean link without `u00253A`  and the rest.This from facebook feed.

Comment: When I print to console I get" LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, "\/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Fhyperwarm&h=4AQEBIq17&s=1");

Comment: basically this is the page .please check it out and the link which appears everywhere has to be retrieved do you have any idea how I can do that ?  http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=15087023444